# Adding elements to a jQuery wrapped element passed to a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

My apologies for not being as clear as I should be. This is a thorough edition of my original post which endeavours to be more specific.

Let the caller

```
myFunction ( $('#tableOne'), anInteger ) );
```

As to the callee :

```
function myFunction ( theTable, theIndex ) {
/* pseudo:
    Without using the first parameter, I could write for instance :
    IT WORKS --> $('#tableOne’ + ‘ #line'  + theIndex ).val(‘blabla’) ;

    Now I want to use the first parameter…
    just replace the first part of the wrapped set —i.e $('#tableOne —
    with the argument —i.e. theTable
*/
}
```

None of these work :

```
theTable + ‘#line'  + theIndex. val(‘blabla’) ;
$( theTable + ‘#line'  + theIndex).val(‘blabla’) ;
theTable.append( ‘#line'  + theIndex).val(‘blabla’) ; // just to make sure…
$(theTable).append( ‘#line'  + theIndex).val(‘blabla’) ; // just to make sure…
$(theTable) + ‘#line'  + theIndex. val(‘blabla’) ;
```

What is the **correct syntax** to implement this within the callee?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a jquery map function to do this.

```
function myFunction (myJQArray, myOtherElement) {

  return $.map(myJQArray, function(myObj, index) {
     var combined = myObj.val() + myOtherElement.val() 
     var withindex = combined + (index+1).toString();
     return withindex;
  }).join(' ');

}
```

Comment: Please hold on: I am dwelling on it all and probably going to edit my original post for the sake of clarity.

Comment: Please check now for my edited post. Looking forward…

Comment: Worked it out for myself as well as I could: please take a look a my own answer and see whether it can be improved.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand what you're trying to do, so on the assumption that you have a bunch of jQuery-wrapped elements in myJQArray and you'd like them to be parented by myOtherElement, you can just do:

```javascript
$('#somePrefix').append($('#ArrayOne'))
```

Comment: Please hold on: I am dwelling on it all and probably going to edit my original post for the sake of clarity.

Comment: Please check now for my edited post. Looking forward…

Comment: Worked it out for myself as well as I could: please take a look a my own answer and see whether it can be improved.

Answer (score 0):

When you are trying to pass `$('#ArrayOne'), $('#somePrefix')` it will pass as a jquery object. There may not be any limitation in passing arguments in this way , provided `myFunction` is ready to handle such arguments.

But when are you are looking for modular design it is better to pass generalized arguments instead of directly referring the jquery object. The reason being the same function can also make to work with other jquery object.

You can do like this

```
myFunction({
 arg1 :$('#ArrayOne'),
arg2:$('#somePrefix')
})
```

Now in  `myFunction` definition will be like this

```
muFunction(options){  // where options is an object which have arg1 & arg2 as key
  // use arg1 & arg2 like this
   var _m = options.arg1;
   var _n = options.arg2;
   // Rest of code
}
```

Comment: Please hold on: I am dwelling on it all and probably going to edit my original post for the sake of clarity.

Comment: Please check now for my edited post. Looking forward…

Comment: Worked it out for myself as well as I could: please take a look a my own answer and see whether it can be improved.

Answer (score 0):

My own solution basically consists in re-wrapping the passed table object after incorporating it into a string that mimics the original wrapped id:

1) OUGHT TO retrieve the id of the jQuery object

```
IDString = theTable.attr ('id);
```

2) using theID, synthetize a wrapped set like so:

```
$('#'+ IDString + ' #line'  + theIndex).val('blabla') ; // Look out for the space before #line
```

I works, though I suspect there exists a more elegant way…